# Qt Haptic Feedback on android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt-mobility

I'm attempting to get my device to rumble but I'm having very little luck. My environment is HTC Sensation Android 2.3.3 API 10. Using Necessitas Qt Creater as my IDE.

Does nothing at all:

```
QFeedbackHapticsEffect::playThemeEffect( QFeedbackHapticsEffect::ThemeBasic );
```

Crashes my application:

```
QFeedbackHapticsEffect rumble;

rumble.setAttackIntensity(0.0);
rumble.setAttackTime(250);
rumble.setIntensity(1.0);
rumble.setDuration(100);
rumble.setFadeTime(250);
rumble.setFadeIntensity(0.0);

rumble.start();

rumble.stop();
```

I've specified my .pro file with the following

```
CONFIG += mobility
MOBILITY += feedback
```

and I'm using QTM_USE_NAMESPACE with the required headers included.

Edit:

I've set the following permissions:

```
android.permission.INTERNET
android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
android.permission.VIBRATE
```

However I still receive a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtmobility-1.2/index.html#platform-compatibility

it's not one of the platforms that is feature complete at the current time.

Answer (score 0):

The API documentation for `QFeedbackHapticsEffect` suggests that `duration` should be greater than `attackTime` + `fadeTime`.  And, of course, stopping right after it starts probably isn't what you want, but hopefully that doesn't cause a seg fault.  Does `actuator()` return something useful?  For that matter, does `QFeedbackActuator::actuators()` give you a non-empty list?

Comment: Maybe I should have made that a comment instead of an answer, since I mostly asked questions...

Comment: Thanks for your time. I have tried your recommendations and had no luck. actuators() returns 2 items.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem and did post a bug report with more details (still without reply) to
http://groups.google.com/group/android-qt/browse_thread/thread/e1a4ad1c797b6694

It seems to be a problem in the Qt Mobility library for Android which probably can be fixed easily for someone who does compile his own library (I didn't do that yet).